# How do i get rid of the last comma? c++ is reading from a file and reading the numbers backwards

Tags: c++, arrays

C++ is reading from a file and printing out the numbers backwards.
i got rid of the comma when it prints out forward. But I cannot figure out how to do the same for back wards.

so far this is what I have:

```
cout<<"Forwards: ";
for (int i=0; i<cnt; i++){
    cout<<setprecision(2)<< fixed;
    if (i == cnt - 1)
    {
        cout << arr[i];
    }
    else
    {
        cout << arr[i] << ", ";
    }
}
cout<<endl;
//printing backwards 
cout << "Backwards: ";
for (int i=cnt-1; i>=0; i--){
    cout<<setprecision(2)<< fixed;
    if (i == cnt + 1)
    {
        cout << arr[i];
    }
    else
    {
        cout << arr[i] << ", ";
    }
```

the forwards part comes out correct:
1.00, 2.00, 3.00, 4.00, 5.00, 6.00, 7.00, 8.00, 9.00, 10.00

but the backwards is what prints out

10.00, 9.00, 8.00, 7.00, 6.00, 5.00, 4.00, 3.00, 2.00, 1.00,

how do I get rid of that last comma

Comment: Once something written to as stream it's hard to get it back out. You're better off by far to not write it in the first place. And since it looks like you're trying to do exactly that, you must have a bug at `if (i == cnt + 1)` . You should be able to pick off in few steps through the loop with a debugger.

Answer (score 2):

Try something like this:

```
bool first_item = true;
for (unsigned int i = 0u; i < LIMIT; ++i)
{
    if (! first_item)
    {
        std::cout << ", ";
    }
    first_item = false;
    std::cout << number;
}
std::cout << "\n";
```

The above code fragment works regardless of the direction, ascending or descending.

The important part is the "flag" to determine if the first item has been printed.

Comment: My go-to for this is `auto delim = “”; for (const auto& x : v) { std::cout << delim << x; delim = “, “; }`. Because string literals are pre-allocated, the assignment is just setting a pointer so it’s very inexpensive.

Answer (score 0):

In the forward-moving loop, `if (i == cnt - 1)` is checking if `i` is on the *last* element of the array.

In the backward-moving loop, you want to check if `i` is on the *first* element, but `if (i == cnt + 1)` will never be true for that check, as `cnt+1` is out of bounds. The *first* element is at index 0, so use `if (i == 0)` instead:

```
cout << "Forwards: ";
cout << setprecision(2) << fixed;
for (int i = 0; i < cnt; ++i){
    if (i == cnt - 1){
        cout << arr[i];
    }
    else{
        cout << arr[i] << ", ";
    }
}
cout << endl;

cout << "Backwards: ";
cout << setprecision(2) << fixed;
for (int i = cnt-1; i >= 0; --i){
    if (i == 0){
        cout << arr[i];
    }
    else{
        cout << arr[i] << ", ";
    }
}
cout << endl;
```

Alternatively, print the 1st output value outside of the loop, and then start the loop on the 2nd output value:

```
cout << "Forwards: ";
cout << setprecision(2) << fixed;
cout << arr[0];
for (int i = 1; i < cnt; ++i){
    cout << ", " << arr[i];
}
cout << endl;

cout << "Backwards: ";
cout << setprecision(2) << fixed;
cout << arr[cnt-1];
for (int i = cnt-2; i >= 0; --i){
    cout << ", " << arr[i];
}
cout << endl;
```

Answer (score 0):

Just write

```
if(i == 0)
```

instead of

```
if(i == cnt+1)
```

It will do the work.